# Is it possible to change the Outlook appointment organizer using Redemption?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have some meetings that were exported to PST's from another instance of Exchange and then were imported to our Exchange environment using the New-MailboxImportRequest PowerShell command.

Since these appointments are copies the organizer is not set to the proper value. In OutlookSpy I can open the appointment, click IMessage and GetRecipientTable. Here I can see that the organizer has a PidTagRecipientFlags value = 3. All other attendees have a value of 513 in the table. I want to change values for the organizer only in hopes that I can set the organizer correctly. This should enable the user to manage the meeting again to complete tasks like rescheduling and cancelling. I was attempting to update these properties (PidTag7BitDisplayName_W, PidTagDisplayName_W, PidTagEmailAddress_W, PidTagRecipientEntryId, PidTagMemberEntryId.) within the RecipientTable using  OutlookSpy but they seem to be read only.

Is it possible to update these values programmatically using Redemption to change the organizer? If so can you provide a code sample to get me started? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can update recipient table properties using `RDORecipient.Fields[]`. Note that `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` is exposed by the Outlook Object Model, but Outlook will refuse to edit some of the properties. Redemption (I am its author) does not have that limitation.

[OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am also its author) will let you modify recipient table  properties - as long as `recipOrganizer` bit (=2) is set, Outlook considers that user the organizer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that new version of OutlookSpy does indeed allow me to update RecipientTable. Despite updating the table though I still can't seem to take ownership of the copied meeting. I must be missing some property. I have the meeting set so that I'm the organizer but is states "This meeting was copied to your calendar and will not receive updates. To receive updates, contact the organizer"  which is also set to me. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Are the PR_SENDER_xyz and PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz properties correctly set?

Comment: I have a PidTagSenderName_W name that I updated and a PidTagSentRepresentingName_W that I updated. But I don't see the two properties you mentioned in the original appointment or the one I'm trying to modify so I can send updates from the copy. I've tried everything I can think of to change the organizer. Starting to think it's not possible based on some research. For example - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2011/09/28/howto-set-the-organizer-of-a-meeting-on-the-calendar-of-an-attendee-using-ews/

Comment: Might not be possible using EWS, but you can still do that using MAPI. Sender name is useless, it is for the UI purposes only, Outlook cares about entry ids. Try to drag all PR_SENDER_xyz and PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz properties from a good message to a message you are trying to modify. You might need to restart Outlook to make sure there is no caching of any kind.